# Morphia save is not working

Tags: mongodb, morphia

why it always getting null value when return in save while using morphia

my id is String

```
private String id;
```

this is my DAO code

```
public Tournament create(Tournament tournament)
{
    Key<Tournament> save = save(tournament);
    if (save != null)
    {
        return getDs().getByKey(Tournament.class, save);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It will save in the data base mongo but return value is null why?

output

```
null
```

if I am using

private ObjectId id

it will get

```
"id":    {
      "timestamp": 1432028968,
      "machineIdentifier": 9913253,
      "processIdentifier": 7516,
      "counter": 8215016
       },
```

I didnt get id in proper value?Please help me I am new in Morphia

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says  save method will update ObjecId field in your Tournament class.

> Saves an entity (Object) and updates the @Id field